# extract log time from log file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How do I extract the time part only from a string like this.

```
[20/06/2016 15:55:42.079] <Messenger> Echo test request
```

I just want  to get  this  part **15:55:42.079** from the log.

Comment: also when posting questions, please bear in mind that you've to show us the effort - in the form of code - put to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is with *parameter expansion* and *substring removal*, e.g.:

```
var="[20/06/2016 15:55:42.079] Echo test request"
tm=${var%]*}     ## remove all from right including ']'
tm=${tm#* }      ## remove all from left including ' '
echo "time $tm"  ## your time is now in $tm
```

Above the operation `${var%]*}` utilizes the `%` operator, which works from the right-to-left removing everything `'*'` until the `]` is reached. Now on the remainder of the string `[20/06/2016 15:55:42.079` a that point, you simply need the `#` operator which removes from left-to-right from the beginning. Here we remove `'*'` (everything) including the `' '` leaving only `15:55:42.079` in the variable `tm`.

Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
awk -F']| ' '{print $2}' <<< "STRING"
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk -F']| ' '{print $2}' <<< "[20/06/2016 15:55:42.079] Echo test request"
15:55:42.079
```

Comment: This is a better approach then mine :) ++

Answer (score 2):

`sed` too is your friend :

```
$ sed -E 's/^[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]([^]]*)\].*$/\1/' 38693974
15:45:42.079
15:55:12.079
15:55:42.079
15:56:42.079
```

Comment: Why not just sub and print $2?

Comment: @123 : I deleted the awk part because the other answer addresses the issue better. And yes ! you're right  `sub and print $2` would've been better with my deleted approach. ;)

Comment: Hie   what  does  this part  **sub(/ \]$/,"")** do . Iam trying to understand  the logic and use  it to print only the  date part only as well **20/06/2016**

Comment: Anything in between `/` and `/` is a  considered a pattern. In your case  `]$` is the pattern. The `$` represents the end of line, So you're checking if an `]` occur just before the end and if so replace it with nothing ie `""` here. For more help you need to see the [\[ gawk \]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) manpage where these functions are explained.